# What's wrong with the Java source code?

Tags: java, java-6

In the Java source from http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/ I get a jar of size ~130mb. The jar don't attach to Eclipse, and inside it has a file called "X_X" of size ~130mb.
Does anyone know what's happening?

**--update**

Thanks Gerco Drie,

now, about this README file:

> JDK requires a high level of
>   technical expertise. (...) If you are not a
>   technical professional in one of these
>   categories, this release is probably
>   not for you.

so, where is the already buid one for me?
I'm using Java 6 update 15.

**--update**

The site http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdkfiles.html says the src.zip is in the root jdk folder (yes, I remember it was last time I needed it), but its not..
Is my jdk a pirate version? :P

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem, but to have the Java source code in Eclipse, normally you would use the `src.zip` in the JDK.

Comment: yes, I used to, but I'm not finding it. Its not inside the JDK folder nither the sun's website.

Comment: Aren't you confusing JRE with JDK? You need to download and install **the JDK**. It's in root of JDK installation folder. E.g. `/path/to/jdk1.6.0_15/src.zip`.

Comment: No. Where is the src.zip supposed to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the jarfile, not extract it or link it to eclipse. The instructions are here:

http://download.java.net/jdk6/6u20/promoted/b01/docs/build/README-JRL.html

> These files are jar files that need to be run, not un-jar'd, for example: `java -jar filename.jar`

I think BalusC is right by the way, this is not the sourcecode you want. You probably want the rt.jar sourcecode, which is in src.zip with the JDK. What you downloaded is the complete sourcecode of the JVM, hotspot compiler, etc included. Although it also includes the class libraries, there is an easier way.

Comment: In the root directory of the JDK. In my case in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\src.zip`. Yours may be different. You may also have chosen not to install the source code when installing the JDK.

Comment: I'll try re-install and look for this option

Answer (score 1):

The distribution you download is a self-extracting file which displays a license YOU MUST ACCEPT before the things you need are extracted.

Run it, and see if it answers your issues.